# how to mirror data from real time database to firestore with cloud function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to deploy a cloud function that copies the information that is in my realtime database to firestore whenever it gets updated. I set the cloud function and called it in my function that saves to my realtime database but it's not performing the cloud function. I'm not getting any errors in the console either. What's the error and how can i fix this? I have provided my code below:

Realtime database setup:

```
studiopick
   studio
     users
        Gcsh31DCGAS2u2XXLuh8AbwBeap1
          email : "Test@gmail.com"
          firstName : "Test"
          lastName : "one"
          phoneNumber : "2223334567"
          prices
          |   roomA
          |     serviceOne
          |       numberInput : "300"
          |       serviceType : "mix n master"
           studioName : "Studio One"
           uid : "Gcsh31DCGAS2u2XXLuh8AbwBeap1"
```

Cloud Function JS:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.updateFirestore = functions.database
  .ref("studiopick/studio/users/{uid}")
  .onWrite((change, context) => {
    const uid = context.params.uid;

    if (!change.after.exists()) {
      return null;
    }
    // Grab the current value of the Realtime Database.
    const data = change.after.val();

    const firestoreDb = admin.firestore();
    const docReference = firestoreDb.collection(uid);

    return docReference.set(
      {
        TransmitterError: data.TransmitterError,
      },
      {merge: true},
    );
});
```

```
const updateFirestore = firebase
  .functions()
  .httpsCallable("updateFirestore");

function updatePrice() {
  //Get data
  numberInput = document.getElementById("numberInput").value;

  const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

  //Enter database location
  firebase
    .database()
    .ref("/studiopick/studio/users/" + user.uid + "/prices/roomA/serviceOne")
    .update({
      numberInput: numberInput,
    });

    updateFirestore(); //This is the copy to firestore function
}
```

Comment: Try the path `ref("studiopick/studio/users/{uid}")` and not `context.params.uid` will be that node's ID.

Comment: Still didn't work. I updated my function

Comment: @Grmln, kindly post your answer so that other community members with similar questions will find your answer helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.updateFirestore = functions.database
  .ref("studiopick/studio/users/{uid}")
  .onWrite((change, context) => {
    const uid = context.params.uid;

    if (!change.after.exists()) {
      return null;
    }
    // Grab the current value of the Realtime Database.
    const data = change.after.val();

    const firestoreDb = admin.firestore();
    const docReference = firestoreDb.collection("studiopick/studios/" + uid);

    return docReference.set(
      {
        TransmitterError: data.TransmitterError,
      },
      {merge: true},
    );
});
```